# How to iterate through javascript object to find multiple similar keys

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a data like this:

```
dictionary: [
  { mercury: 'MERC' },
  { venus: 'VEN' },
  { earth: 'EART' },
  { mars: 'MAR' },
  { jupiter: 'JUP' },
  { saturn: 'SAT' },
  { uranus: 'ANUS' },
  { neptune: 'NEP' },
  { pluto: 'PLUT' },
]
```

When a user types letters inside an input field like `v`, I want to show the closest similar string from the object, which would be `'VEN'` for this, I have the following code:

```
let word = 'v'
let result = dictionary.find(d => {
  var str = Object.keys(d)[0]
  if (str.toLowerCase().indexOf(word.toLowerCase()) == 0) {
    return result = str
  }
})
```

This code works well, and result returns the found string. The problem is that when someone types `m` I only get `MERC` but I should get multiple results because `mercury` and `mar` both start with `m`.

Is there an way to do this with find, or other function?

Comment: If you're trying to implement autocomplete, see this https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: This `indexOf(word.toLowerCase()) == 0` should be `indexOf(word.toLowerCase()) >= 0`

Comment: Define CLOSEST SIMILAR before doing anything else :) Is it string containing the substring as a whole, containing each character in substring, starting with substring, ending with it, both..

Comment: You don't need to use jquery/UI for a simple autocomplete.

Comment: Also, it's 2018, who uses Jquery UI anymore....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could filter the array and use just the values.

```js
var dictionary = dictionary = [{ mercury: 'MERC' }, { venus: 'VEN' }, { earth: 'EART' }, { mars: 'MAR' }, { jupiter: 'JUP' }, { saturn: 'SAT' }, { uranus: 'ANUS' }, { neptune: 'NEP' }, { pluto: 'PLUT' }],
    word = 'm',
    result = dictionary
        .filter(d => Object.keys(d)[0].toLowerCase().startsWith(word))
        .map(o => Object.values(o)[0]);

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, do you think this method is efficient if I have like 6K word in my json file? I was told filter exits on first find so if a user was to search for a word like 'human' then every letter typed would do a loop over all 6 entries. Is there a better (optimized) way to do this without using a database?

Comment: please add the real data structure to the question. for really fas access. i would use a simple `for` loop which is faster than any array method.

Answer (score 3):

`find` returns only one value.

Use `Object.values` and `filter`

```
var search = "m";
search = search.toLowerCase();
var output = Object.values(dictionary).map(s => Object.values(s)[0].toLowerCase()).filter(s => s.indexOf(search) == 0);
console.log( output );
```

**Demo**

```js
var dictionary = [{
    mercury: 'MERC'
  },
  {
    venus: 'VEN'
  },
  {
    earth: 'EART'
  },
  {
    mars: 'MAR'
  },
  {
    jupiter: 'JUP'
  },
  {
    saturn: 'SAT'
  },
  {
    uranus: 'ANUS'
  },
  {
    neptune: 'NEP'
  },
  {
    pluto: 'PLUT'
  },
];
var search = "m";
search = search.toLowerCase();
var output = Object.values(dictionary).map(s => Object.values(s)[0].toLowerCase()).filter(s => s.indexOf(search) == 0);
console.log( output );
```

**Edit**

To return in the original case, use toLowerCase before doing `indexOf`

```
var output = Object.values( dictionary ).map(
       s => Object.values( s )[0] ).filter(
         s => s.toLowerCase().indexOf( search ) == 0);
```

Comment: @Liam Sorry, but the link you have shared points to my answer itself. Didn't understood your point.

Comment: @Liam I think OP has mentioned *because mercury and mar both start with m*.

Answer (score 1):

Using function `filter` to get your targets.

```js
var dictionary = [
  { mercury: 'MERC' },
  { venus: 'VEN' },
  { earth: 'EART' },
  { mars: 'MAR' },
  { jupiter: 'JUP' },
  { saturn: 'SAT' },
  { uranus: 'ANUS' },
  { neptune: 'NEP' },
  { pluto: 'PLUT' }
];

let word = 'm';
let result = dictionary.filter(d => Object.values(d)[0].toLowerCase().indexOf(word) > -1)


 console.log(result)
```

If you want the values, use `map` function.

```js
var dictionary = [
  { mercury: 'MERC' },
  { venus: 'VEN' },
  { earth: 'EART' },
  { mars: 'MAR' },
  { jupiter: 'JUP' },
  { saturn: 'SAT' },
  { uranus: 'ANUS' },
  { neptune: 'NEP' },
  { pluto: 'PLUT' }
];

let word = 'm';
let result = dictionary.filter(d => Object.values(d)[0].toLowerCase().indexOf(word) > -1)


 console.log(result.map((b) => Object.values(b)[0]))
```

Comment: what have you changed and why